# Should I denormalize to a join with an added bit, or what?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-normalization

I have many documents in my system such as order invoices, requisitions etc. In order to track their approval workflow I have one common table in which I have the following columns.

```
WFID  ActionDate  DocInstancetype DocinstanceID  iscurrent   status
1     2017-04-04      PO              58            0       Submitted
2     2017-04-05      PO              58            1       Approved
3     2017-04-04      PR              74            1       Submitted
```

In my reports I usually need to consider only approved documents. Is it a good idea to add an `IsApproved` bit in the Documents Master table (in PR and PO tables) and sync it using a trigger so that I can avoid a join with workflow table every time I need to get approved documents only?

Any other better suggestion would also be appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to give advice since a lot of information is missing here. What do the tables PO and PR look like, what is the meaning of each table's content, how do the three tables relate to one another? One suggestion right now, if you need to "sync" tables, chances are that the table to be synched should really be a view.

Comment: Better is to use view; if speed is concern, you can even use materialized one. Triggers may become tricky and deadlock-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Document table should contain the status (not is_approved) because you might need to filter document on basis of document status in future though today your need are limited to status="approved". Status change history should be maintain in another table which is `workflow` in your case but I would suggest `document_status_tracking' or just 'document_tracking' would be a better name for the table.